# How to make authenticated supabase queries from a NextJS api route?

Tags: next.js, supabase

I'm having some trouble with the documentation, and can't seem to figure out how I'm supposed to authenticate my requests to the database. I have RLSs that allow users to only alter things that they own , i.e. which have a column with their user_id.

So far, on the client I have this snippet:

```
const session = await supabase.auth.getSession();
const jwt = session.data.session?.access_token;
try {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/word/${route}`, {
    method,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
      apiKey: jwt as string,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(word),
  });
```

Which sends the JWT to my server, from which point I want to perform DB queries.

However I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use the JWT server-side in order to do that.
I've tried creating a new supabase client with the JWT, but that doesn't work.
Other examples I see online are for supabase v1, like supabase.api.setAuth(jwt), or something like that, which doesn't work.

Right now this is my api route. I decided to import the auth helpers library as it seemed the most viable way to try to move forward:

```
export default async function handler(
   req: NextApiRequest,
   res: NextApiResponse<Data | string>
) {
  try {
   const word = req.body;
   const jwt = req.headers.authorization;

const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient({
  req,
  res,
});

const user = await supabase.auth.getUser(jwt);

const { count, error } = await supabase
  .from("words")
  .select("name", { head: true, count: "exact" })
  .eq("name", word);

if (count) {
  res.status(409).send("Word already saved");
} else {
  // TODO handle error
  const { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("words")
    .insert({ name: word, user_id: user?.id });

  console.log(data, error);
  res.status(200).send("OK");
}
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
  }
}
```

The user variable created here, which is equal to await supabase.auth.getUser(jwt) has null data and an error message saying "no Route matched with those values"

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you cannot just insert the data from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

supabase will try to get user from cookie first then try to get jwt from header

```
import { User, createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { cookies, headers } from 'next/headers';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest, { params }: { params: any }) {
  const supabaseCookie = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });

  const {
    data: { session: cookieSession }
  } = await supabaseCookie.auth.getSession();

  let currentUser = cookieSession?.user;
  if (!currentUser) {
    const headersList = headers();
    const authorization = headersList.get('authorization');
    const [bearer, token] = authorization?.split(' ') as string[];
    const { data: userResponse } = await supabaseCookie.auth.getUser(token);
    currentUser = userResponse.user as User;
  }

  return NextResponse.json(currentUser, {
    status: 200
  });
}
```